# Accessibility support for keyboard with span element

Tags: jquery, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have a few elements that can be clicked and work as buttons. However, they are not visible to screen readers. To correct this I am trying to add a function that will add such support to any element that has the role set as button.

```
<span role="button">clickable</span>
```

I wrote this jQuery function, but it doesn't quite work.

```
$(document).on("keypress", "[role='button']", function(e) {
    var code = e.which;
    // 13 = Return, 32 = Space
    if ((code === 13) || (code === 32)) {
        $(this).click();
    });
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is the button not visible in the UI, or you cant trigger click?

Comment: why not reverse the logic here, why not style a button to look like a span (and then style it from there). Will throw a quick example up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<span>`s aren't normally focusable; without focus it won't capture keypresses.

You can put a `tabindex` on it, as discussed on the [MDN button role page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role).

When designing for accessability, particularly when using non-standard UX elements as UX inputs, `tabindex` becomes super-important... and super-annoying.

Comment: I tested with tabindex="0" but it didn't seem to work. Let me give it another try.

Comment: @santa Just *having* a tabindex is insufficient, it must be focused. It works fine once focused in a jsfiddle. I'm sure you're already doing this, but also make sure you're testing under a screen reader--the UX is *very* different, and in order for it to make sense, it *must* be tested in the real environment.

Comment: The above should work fine for you, `tabindex="0"` will make it focusable and the code you wrote will work (don't forget to also add 'onclick' handlers). +1

Comment: @santa You may also be getting the wrong element (I don't remember jQuery), you may want `$(e.target).click()` or something. https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/gcu3xapv/

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a `<button>` - you can style them to look like a `<span>` and benefit from all the native functionality.

I might have missed a style that a certain browser may need as doing it off the top of my head but you get the idea.

**important** - the below shows you how to 'reset' a `<button>` - please do not use this in production without adding some differentiation between the button and surrounding text.

```css
html{
   font-size: 1em;
}
.like-span{
  background: none; /*essential*/
 border: none; /*essential*/
 padding: 0; /*essential*/
 font: inherit; /*important as otherwise the text will look slightly different*/
  color: inherit; /*if you want the span the same colour as the rest of the sentence*/
 cursor: pointer; /*make sure you add this, but if you really want it to behave like a span you would leave this out*/
 outline: inherit; /*I would not recommend this as it removes focus indicator, but is fine as part of a reset if you are adding your own style */
}
.blue{
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sentence with a <button class="like-span">button</button> that looks just like a span</p>
<p class="blue">This is a sentence with a <button class="like-span">button</button> that looks just like a span</p>
```

Comment: This will probably work, however I'm trying to write a broad function that will work for any element with role="button". Thanks

Comment: What use case do you have that it cannot be a `<button>`? `role="button" is one of the things that nearly always points to poor HTML (although there are exceptions)